# C# .NET Cryptography don't decrypt properly

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a text in C# (.NET 3.5) figuring out that this simple code doesn't work:

```
    private const string KEY = "Chiave";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string plainText = "Data to be encrypted";

        byte[] keyArray;
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KEY));

        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] encArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

        tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] decArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(encArray, 0, encArray.Length);

        if (encArray.Length == decArray.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < encArray.Length; ++i)
                Console.Out.Write("{0,3}|{1,3}", encArray[i], decArray[i]);
        } else
            Console.Out.Write("Length error!");

        Console.In.Read();
    }
```

It seems the encrypt or decrypt phase messes up some bytes in the beginning of the text (in a different way any time I run the program) sometimes changing even the length of the byte array.
I was able to make it work using ECB cipher, but my data has some static blocks which leads to the same result any time.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode(v=vs.110).aspx about ECB:

> Important:  This mode is not recommended because it opens the door for
>   multiple security exploits. If the plain text to be encrypted contains
>   substantial repetition, it is feasible for the cipher text to be
>   broken one block at a time. It is also possible to use block analysis
>   to determine the encryption key. Also, an active adversary can
>   substitute and exchange individual blocks without detection, which
>   allows blocks to be saved and inserted into the stream at other points
>   without detection.

These are some results after the enc. and dec.:

```
��u��T�be encrypted
U����ŋbe encrypted
5�AL\"0be encrypted
```

And so on, thanks in advice.

Comment: That's because of the IV. Sorry, gotta sleep, you'll find examples now you know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a new instance of the `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` but this new instance has not the same IV value of the first one

Also, it is not correct to compare the length of the encrypted array with the length of the decrypted one. You should try to get back the original string and check if the two are equal

```
private const string KEY = "Chiave";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string plainText = "Data to be encrypted";

    byte[] keyArray;
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KEY));

    byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tdes.Key = keyArray;
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] encArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

    // REMOVE THESE LINES 
    // tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    // tdes.Key = keyArray;
    // tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    // tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] decArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(encArray, 0, encArray.Length);

    // if (encArray.Length == decArray.Length)
    // {
    //    for (int i = 0; i < encArray.Length; ++i)
    //        Console.Out.Write("{0,3}|{1,3}", encArray[i], decArray[i]);
    //} else
    //    Console.Out.Write("Length error!");

    string result = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decArray);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.In.Read();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was IV (I omitted the computation of the result string as base64 encoding of the encrypted text to be sure it was not an encoding problem)